# No module named flask with waitress-serve and virtualenv (App engine flex)

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-import, waitress

I'm working on a project which used to be run on Linux for test. It's an App Engine flex project, run with gunicorn. Gunicorn does not work on Windows if I understood well, so I've been adviced to use waitress.
I also use virtualenv in my project.

So when I'm in my virtualenv, I run `waitress-serve main:app` (the gunicorn cmd was `gunicorn -b :8080 main:app`). I get an error: `It had these arguments:
1. No module named flask`.

I use flask. I can see the flask folder in my virtualenv folder. And when I run `python` then `from flask import Flask` I have no error.

Is there compat issue between waitress and virtualenv ? Or I'm doing something else wrong ? (already tried to delete virtualenv folder and install all the things again)

Answer (score 0):

Python modules are case sensitive

Try `Flask` not `flask`.

Comment: If I do `import Flask`, I get an `ImportError` (with waitress and with python cli)